# Was Regan committing profanations?

Tags: the-exorcist

In the movie *The Exorcist* (1973), in the first part of it we see a priest that discovers profanations in a church.

Later in the movie, we was told that the profanations are linked to satanic rituals (and Regan's possession).

In the novel there's a part that is missing in the movie: the detective Kinderman analyzes the paint of the sculpture made by Regan for her mother and discovers that the same paint was used to make the profanations in the church and fingerprints of a "little hand (probably hand of a kid)" were found on a paper left by the guilty.

Did Regan commit profanations?

Those profanations were done before Regan shows signs of possession, so it makes me think that Regan was possessed before when we see it.

Comment: I was unaware that "profanation" was a noun, but that's a correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

There were several events in the book that could lead a reader to two conclusions: either Regan was committing these terrible acts (and was presumably insane), or the demon was committing them and leaving clues that would point to Reagan.  Some made it into the movie; others did not.  The paint was one example.  Another was Burke Dennings' death: in the book, some time after Burke's death, Regan's mother Chris discovers a book in Regan's room that had a page torn, in such a way that it was clear that he was in the girl's room shortly before he died.  Was he killed by an insane Regan? or the demon?  In other words, was Regan actually possessed or not?

It is my belief that these acts were there to place doubt in the mind of Chris (and the reader) as to what was actually happening.  *The Exorcist* is a well-crafted and well-written story that has many levels beyond the scary monster plot on the surface, and your question reveals that some of them have affected you -- just as it should be.